# Disqus Integration with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, disqus

We just want to integrate Disqus commenting system with our asp.net mvc application that is being tried with Disqus SSO features. The steps are followed as described in below urls:

1. http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-single-sign-on
2. http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472100-author-specific-moderation

But can not post comment with implemented Disqus SSO.

Following items are used/referred to integrate with Disqus SSO:

1. https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/cs/sso/DisqusSSO.cs
2. JS implementation, refer Snap-1
3. Controller/Action implementation, refer Snap-2
4. How it runs, refer Snap-3

Also referred following sample: https://github.com/Gigya-Inc/disqus-integration-demo

We are missing anything to achieve our goal - "Our application's authenticated users able to comment through Disqus without re-login"?

Or are there any better ways?

Images:

-------------- Snap-1 ------------------------
[image]

--------------- Snap-2 -----------------------
[image]

--------------------- Snap-3 -----------------
[image]

**UPDATE - 03 March 2013**
After SSO registration, plan 99.0USD, we tried to integrate it again but good luck is still far away! See below image, however, we have not change any code. Just changed the secret and public key based on our new sso enabled account.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll only work if your account has added the Disqus SSO add-on, which can be done here: https://disqus.com/account/addons/signup/

Everything else looks correct to me.

Comment: please refer updated question. A single word gives us a great help. Thanks.